# Javascript: Comparing standard functions always returns *false*

Tags: javascript, nan

Im trying to understand why comparing standard functions always returns a Boolean `false`

Like for the isNaN function

```
>isNaN === true
false 
>isNaN === false
false
```

But

```
>Boolean(isNaN)
true
```

Now to make things a little more interesting

```
>!isNaN === false
true
>!isNaN === true
false
```

This occurs with standard function like Number, Object etc.

Does anyone know what happens under the hood in JavaScript ?

Comment: `===` is Strict Equality Comparison operator, _Strict equality compares two values for equality. Neither value is implicitly converted to some other value before being compared. If the values have different types, the values are considered unequal._ see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Comment: `===` only returns true when its operands are the same type. `'5' !== 5`, `0 !== false`. (`isNaN == true` isn’t true either, but there’s really no reason to expect it to behave the same way as a cast to boolean. In `2 == true`, would you cast `true` to a number or `2` to a boolean?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you read [truthy and falsy](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) values, in short, isNaN is a function, it actually exists, so you can use it as a short hand for `true` checking, very useful for everyday programming.

When you use `===` type checking is done, and then a bool != a function.

When you pre-pend `!` to it, you are actually casting to boolean type and reversing the value to `true` so that is why the comparison changes.

Comment: Thanks. The link helped me understand the concepts more accurately.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the lists of [Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values.

isNaN is truthy because it's a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
>isNaN === true
false 
>isNaN === false
false
```

Because `isNaN` is a function.

---

```
>Boolean(isNaN)
true
```

Because again, `isNaN` is a function and functions are truthy values. Please refer following to see [output specs for Boolean](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2)